# My constructors are not well defined?

Tags: java

I have a table named Album with 4 columns the CodeA is a primary key of type char.

Then my second table is Collabo with 1 column named CodeA which is a foreign key always of type char.

[here is a preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Esev.png) 
I tried displaying in my Jframe Collabo the CodeA but I have error message from my table DaoCollabo.

**no suitable constructor found for Album(String)constructor Album.Album() is not applicable(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)constructor Album.Album(String,String,Chanteur,Date) is not applicable(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)**

What do you think of my class Album and Collabo?

**Class Album**

```
public class Album {
    private String codeA;
    private String titreA;
    private Chanteur chantAlb;
    private Date dateApp; //


    public Album() {
    }

    public Album(String codeA, String titreA, Chanteur chantAlb, Date dateApp) {
        this.codeA = codeA;
        this.titreA = titreA;
        this.chantAlb = chantAlb;
        this.dateApp = dateApp;
    }

    public String getCodeA() {
        return codeA;
    }

    public void setCodeA(String codeA) {
        this.codeA = codeA;
    }

    public String getTitreA() {
        return titreA;
    }

    public void setTitreA(String titreA) {
        this.titreA = titreA;
    }

    public Chanteur getChantAlb() {
        return chantAlb;
    }

    public void setChantAlb(Chanteur chantAlb) {
        this.chantAlb = chantAlb;
    }

    public Date getDateApp() {
        return dateApp;
    }

    public void setDateApp(Date dateApp) {
        this.dateApp = dateApp;
    }

   public String getDateAppBE() {
        String tmp;

        if (this.dateApp == null)
          tmp = "";
        else
          {
          SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
          tmp = dateParser.format(this.dateApp);
          }
        return tmp;
    }

    public void setDateAppBE(String dateApp) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        try {
            this.dateApp = dateParser.parse(dateApp);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Album.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public String getDateAppSQL() {
        String tmp;

        if (this.dateApp == null)
          tmp = "";
        else
          {
          SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          tmp = "'" + dateParser.format(this.dateApp) + "'";
          }
        return tmp;
    }

    public String getDateAppUS() {
        String tmp;

        if (this.dateApp == null)
          tmp = "";
        else
          {
          tmp = this.dateApp.toString();
          }
        return tmp;
    }
```

**My Class Collabo**

```
public class Collabo {
    private Album appAlb;

    public Collabo() {
    }
    public Collabo(Album appAlb) {
        this.appAlb = appAlb;
    }
    public Album getAppAlb() {
        return appAlb;
    }
    public void setAppAlb(Album appAlb) {
        this.appAlb = appAlb;
    }
```

**DAOCollabo**

```
public ArrayList <Collabo> selectCollabos()
    {
        ArrayList <Collabo> myList = new ArrayList();


        String req = "Select A.CodeA from album A, collabo C where A.CodeA = C.CodeA order by 1 ";
        ResultSet resu = ConnexionMySQL.getInstance().selectQuery (req);
        try {
            while (resu.next())
            {  
                //creation de l'objet Collabo
                myList.add (new Collabo(resu.getString(1), 
                             new Album (resu.getString(2))));
             }
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        return myList;
    }
```

Comment: show the code where from the Dao where you fetch the data. The error message says that you are calling a constructor in `Album` that does not exist. you are trying to call a one parameter constructor,

Comment: yes the dao code is needed. My guess is that it is trying to covert collaboration.CodeA (char6) to Collabo.appA1b(Album) ie String to Album

Comment: **no suitable constructor found for Album(String)** means that you do not have defined a constructor `public Album(String codeA)`. The solution depends on the calling code, either you have to create such a constructor in the class `Album` or you have to call one already defined. Depends on the needs of the calling code...

Comment: @ Jack Flamp ; I edited my message with the code Dao

Comment: What is the purpose of `Collabo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Album (resu.getString(2))
```

requires a constructor that takes a single `String` parameter:

```
public Album(String codeA) {
    this.codeA = codeA;
}
```

Comment: thank you a lot !!! I again have ask please; I have error message java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1. where do I go to solve this problem ? Thank you again for help

Comment: That is a totally different problem, please create a separate question for it and provide the code. That will gain a lot more attention than just mine. First guess is that you are trying to access a third column in a table that has only two columns.

Comment: thank you a lot (dank u)

Comment: Pas de cause (you're welcome)!